# cvShowImage error

Tags: c++, opencv

Ok. With a help of SO I have managed to put together this code. There is one more error though:

```
    // ...

    std::vector<char> jpegBuffer(lSize);

    // copy the file into the buffer.
    fread(&jpegBuffer[0], 1, jpegBuffer.size(), pFile);

    // terminate
    fclose (pFile);

    Mat matrixJpeg = cv::imdecode(Mat(jpegBuffer), 1);

    IplImage fIplImageHeader = matrixJpeg;

    cvShowImage("Video", fIplImageHeader);
    char key = cvWaitKey();
```

There is one more error with this code though. It is at this line:

```
cvShowImage("Video", fIplImageHeader);
```

And the error is:

```
/home/richard/Desktop/richard/client/src/main.cc:106: error: cannot convert ‘IplImage’ to ‘const CvArr*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void cvShowImage(const char*, const CvArr*)’
```

According to the docs Mat and IplImage should be interchangable and this:

```
IplImage fIplImageHeader = matrixJpeg;
```

Should be all that is needed to convert Mat to IplImage.

Comment: I don't understand your query.  You say that IplImage and Mat are interchangeable, but I don't see how that has anything to do with the given error, unless Mat is a typedef for CvArr*.

Comment: cvShowImage has always worked for me when I just used IplImaeg as second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CvArr*` is a typedef for `void*`

You must specify the forced type conversion:

```
csShowImage("Whatever", static_cast<CvArr*>(somePointer));
```

Also note that `somePointer` is a **pointer.**

*You might say something like*

```
IplImage object = matrix;
IplImage* somePointer = &object;
```

Also, I kind of doubt it that arbitrary image type is substitutable with a matrix type. What are you willing to achieve when you tell your program to **show the matrix**?

Comment: That gives me: /home/richard/Desktop/richard/client/src/main.cc:106: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘IplImage’ to type ‘CvArr*’

Comment: See the description below. In your case you could just use `static_cast<x>(&fIplImageHeader)`.

Comment: I'm trying to show a jpg image from buffer. I have jpg images in the memory and I need to show it.

Comment: Thank you that works :) I'm really not that good with C++ so this little piece of code was giving me a headache.

Comment: Hm, that's not very obvious. I thought `Mat` was some kind of an alias for a math-like matrix type, but seems like it's the data structure to hold `a x b` raw byte matrices, for example. Didn't know that.

Comment: I'd recommend you to understand what's happening beneath that `static_cast` and read about pointers, because that's the place where you should be accurately and know what you're doing.

Comment: I know I should really take a look into C++ to understand it better but I just needed to get this working very fast and did not have time to study C++ in depth.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
IplImage* fIplImageHeader = matrixJpeg;
```

IplImage* and Mat* should be interchangeable.